# Strategy for sharing resources between projects

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, resources, satellite-assembly

I have a central library (DLL) called Core that is used by many projects (Some web apps, some win forms, some other class libraries).

Some resources are stored in the Core library.

When I need to use a resource file in the Core library, I need to know what the culture info is. Because it is sometimes used in a win form app, sometimes in a web app, I can't really use the culture from HttpContext or from the CurrentThread.

I imagine that this a common problem, so I am wondering :

What's a good strategy to pass the culture information around between DAL dlls and UI projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always get the culture from the CurrentThread. It's supported both in WinForms and Web Applications. Even better: you'll probably won't need to bother about this at all, as the resource manager in .NET will handle this based on the current culture.

Comment: And the current culture in a web app will be set with the culture of the user (and not the culture of the server running the web app)?

Comment: @Hugo it is up to the web application to set the current thread's CurrentCulture/CurrentUICulture on each request. They'll find out real quick if they aren't doing it right.

Comment: Thanks, setting the culture info from the UI thread and getting it down that way makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the ui culture for a thread.

Then you are already fixed in case of WinForms.

In aspnet, you will need to set current ui culture for the thread. You can hook this procedure in a base controller's OnActionExecuted for this purpose (MVC) or use the PreInit event (webforms).
This also can be done in an HttpModule.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information on controllers / event handlers, will be useful.